# CSV Import issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I have this to parse a CSV file:

```
csv_file = CSV.parse(
  file.read(),
  headers:              true,
  header_converters:    :symbol
)
```

It works, but I want to specify the encoding type so I add: `{encoding: 'UTF-8'}` into the read method as below:

```
csv_file = CSV.parse(
  file.read({encoding: 'UTF-8'}),
  headers:              true,
  header_converters:    :symbol
)
```

But I get this error: can't convert Hash into Integer

I just can't see what is wrong. I have checked the docs but it says you can pass the encoding in like so but it does need the file as the first argument so it could be stalling there but surely as it already knows what file is is reading it should be ok.

How can I solve this?

**Update:**

I have updated to the following:

```
def import
  if params[:import_coasters]
    file = params[:import_coasters][:file]
    Park.import_from_csv(file)


def self.import_from_csv(file)
  Park.destroy_all
```

and

```
  csv_file = CSV.parse(
    File.read(file, {encoding: 'UTF-8'}),
    headers:              true,
    header_converters:    :symbol
  )
```

But I get the following error:

can't convert ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into String

Comment: how are you creating the file variable? I'm having trouble recreating your issue in order to test it.

Comment: Can you please point to the docs that say you can use #read in this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. Try this:

```
# Step 1: convert the uploaded file object to a file name
uploaded_file = params[:import_coasters][:file]
file_name = uploaded_file.path

# Step 2: To get the input text and see if it's what you expect
text = File.read(
  file_name, 
  {encoding: 'UTF-8'}
)

# Parse the text
csv_file = CSV.parse(
  text,
  headers: true,
  header_converters: :symbol
)
```

From the Ruby 1.9.3 docs on IO.read:

"If the last argument is a hash, it specifies option for internal open(). The key would be the following. open_args: is exclusive to others."

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-read

Also, look at the documentation for `UploadedFile` because it's not actually a typical Ruby File object:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html

Comment: Any ideas on this? I really can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your updates are a totally different question-- this isn't really about CSV parsing. You are mixing up the file input parameter with a file name. To see this, do more step-by-step and show yourself the output of each step: what class is your file parameter? if it's a string, is it a valid file name? if so, are you able to open the file for reading? if so, does the text encoding work right?

Answer (score 1):

It is because File.read() expect a filename as the first argument. You are passing ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile instead. If you look at the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html), you'll see that UploadedFile already has a read method, so you can try:

```
   csv_file = CSV.parse(
    file.read({encoding: 'UTF-8'}),
    headers:              true,
    header_converters:    :symbol
  )
```